# Ruby => How to match a string that contains #and a number example #56

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby => How to match a string that contains #and a number example #56

for example i have a string "my roll number is #256767"

i should match whether the string has # symbol and a number beside it

Answer (score 2):

Use Ruby's [`match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match)

```
!"my roll number is #256767".match(/#\d+/).nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
m = s.match(/^.*(#\d+).*$/)
unless m.nil?
  puts m[1]
end
```

Comment: This only tests if the string **ends** with `#n` where `n` is an integer. Both of OP's examples will work with this regex, but it's not exactly what he's asked.